# Android application crashing after updating from playstore only

Tags: android, sqlite, proguard, android-contentprovider, android-proguard

I have recently updated [My Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrapps.statusandquotes) with version 1.2, In that I am using inbuilt database to show data. I have copied database first time from assets and used **ContentProvider** to access data from database.

Its working fine with first install but getting error if any user update app from playstore.

**Error Log** which Reported by User:

### Report 1:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: utp (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE quotes SET liked=?,utp=? WHERE _id=1183
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1574)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1522)
    at com.emergingcoders.database.QuoteContentProvider.update(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.update(ContentProvider.java:355)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1360)
    at com.emergingcoders.a.c$a.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

### Report 2 (getting in same activity):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.support.v4.content.o$3.done(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: utp (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE (liked=1) ORDER BY utp DESC
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
    at com.emergingcoders.database.QuoteContentProvider.query(Unknown Source)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1017)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:238)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
    at android.support.v4.content.c.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.b$c.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.k.h(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.k.d(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.a.e(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.a$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.a$a.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.content.o$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 3 more
```

### Report 3:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mrapps.statusandquotes/com.emergingcoders.activities.TodaysQuotesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
    at com.emergingcoders.activities.TodaysQuotesActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    ... 9 more
```

### proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager {
    public <init>(...);
}

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawable { *; }

# support design
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-keep class uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.* { *; }
-keep class uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.*$* { *; }

-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

# Only necessary if you downloaded the SDK jar directly instead of from maven.
-keep class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }

-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep class com.emergingcoders.model.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```

I am not updating database version in new update, I tried a lot to find but don't know why it happened after updating app only.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you doing the copying? If there is any difference from [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/), you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not provided the proper update script for your database.  If the app is run from scratch (ie. doesn't have an existing Database) this will work fine (since there is no database migration required)

Research the SQLHelper classes, which provide methods to allow you to migrate Database versions.

To be clear, it is the database Schema you need to update, not the data (there is a column, missing in your schema, which the error states):

```
no such column: utp
```

Comment: I am not updating database on any update because its just copied first time only.